# Event listeners in SpriteVisualElement not responding

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, event-handling

I have embedded Flashpunk game library to my Flex/Air project where some Flex components are rendered on top of the FP. Things show correctly and Flex components respond to mouse input. Flashpunk however doesn't. I embedded it like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                       resize="windowedapplication1_resizeHandler(event)"
                       initialize="init();"
                       applicationComplete="complete();"
                       showStatusBar="false"
                       mouseEnabled="false"
                       xmlns:local="*">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->

    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:SpriteVisualElement id="flashpunk" depth="-2" mouseEnabled="true" mouseChildren="true">
    </s:SpriteVisualElement>

    <mx:MenuBar id="myMenubar" width="832" itemClick="menuHandler(event);" labelField="@label" depth="0">
        <fx:XMLList xmlns="">
            <item label="File">
                <item label="New" id="new" />
                <item label="Open" id="open"/>
                <item label="Save" id="save"/>
                <item label="Save As" id="saveas"/>
                <item label="Quit" id="quit"/>
            </item>

            <item label="Edit">
                <item label="Undo" id="undo"/>
                <item label="Redo" id="redo"/>
                <item label="Preferences" id="preferences"/>
            </item>

            <item label="Level">
                <item label="New Scene" id="newroom"/>
                <item label="Properties" id="properties"/>
            </item>

            <item label="Objects">
                <item label="Clickable" id="clickable"/>
                <item label="Character" id="character"/>
                <item label="Door" id="door"/>
                <item label="Treasure" id="treasure"/>
            </item>
        </fx:XMLList>


    </mx:MenuBar>









    <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[
            import basicui.Global;
            import basicui.NewUI;

            import flash.display.NativeWindow;
            import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
            import flash.filesystem.File;

            import mx.collections.*;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.core.IUIComponent;
            import mx.core.InteractionMode;
            import mx.core.mx_internal;
            import mx.effects.effectClasses.FadeInstance;
            import mx.events.FlexNativeWindowBoundsEvent;
            import mx.events.MenuEvent;
            import mx.events.ResizeEvent;
            import mx.utils.object_proxy;

            import net.flashpunk.FP;
            import net.flashpunk.Screen;

            import org.osmf.elements.F4MElement;

            import spark.components.Application;
            import spark.components.supportClasses.InteractionState;


            public var Maini:Main = new Main; 
            public static var windowsize:Point = new Point(640, 480);
            private var started:Boolean = false;





            private function init():void
            {

                flashpunk.addChild(Maini);
                Global.main = this;


            }

            private function complete():void
            {

                stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
                stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;


                //calculate system chrome
                //nativeWindow.width = 640;
                //nativeWindow.height = 480;
                Global.chromew=nativeWindow.width-nativeWindow.stage.stageWidth;
                Global.chromeh=nativeWindow.height-nativeWindow.stage.stageHeight;

                Global.uibarh = 50;
                //default windowsize
                resizewindow(windowsize.x, windowsize.y);
                started = true;


            }

            public function resizewindow(w:int, h:int):void
            {


                if (w < 640)
                    w = 640;
                if (h < 480)
                    h = 480;
                windowsize.x = w+Global.chromew;
                windowsize.y = h+Global.chromeh+Global.uibarh;



                nativeWindow.width = w+Global.chromew;
                nativeWindow.height = h +Global.chromeh+Global.uibarh;


                myMenubar.width = nativeWindow.width;

                //resize flashpunk
                FP.width = nativeWindow.width; 
                FP.height =  nativeWindow.height; 
                FP.screen = new net.flashpunk.Screen;
                FP.bounds.width = Number(FP.width);
                FP.bounds.height = Number(FP.height);
            }


            private function menuHandler(evt:MenuEvent):void  
            {
                // Don't open the Alert for a menu bar item that 
                // opens a popup submenu.
                if (evt.item.@id == "new")
                {

                    var a:NewUI = new NewUI;
                    a.begin(this);
                    addElement(a);

                }

                if (evt.item.@id == "open")
                {
                    var filter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Levels", "*.ael");
                    var file:File = new File;
                    file.browseForOpen("",[filter]);

                    file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileselected);

                }



                if (evt.item.@id == "quit")
                {
                    //close the program
                    //could ask if there is unsaved data...?
                    close();

                }


                    /*Alert.show("Label: " + evt.item.@label + "\n" + 
                        "Data: " + evt.item.@data, "Clicked menu item");
                    */

            }

            private function fileselected(event:Event):void
            {
                //user selected a file:


                File(event.currentTarget).addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileloaded)
                File(event.currentTarget).load();

            }

            private function fileloaded(event:Event):void
            {
                //user selected file is loaded:

                Global.levelfile = File(event.currentTarget);
                Global.levelXML = XML(File(event.currentTarget).data.toString());
                //initialize level project
                Global.editor.initlevel();
            }


            protected function windowedapplication1_resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (started)
                {
                    windowsize.x = nativeWindow.width;
                    windowsize.y = nativeWindow.height
                    myMenubar.width = nativeWindow.width;
                }
            }

        ]]>

    </fx:Script>



</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Flashpunk library has its own event listeners for input "Input.as". For some reason they seem to not run. I suppose that the flex components somehow hijacks these listeners or that the SpriteVisualElement doesn't allow or recognize them. How I can enable SpriteVisualElement event listeners? Is there setting I need to set or something? Note that neither mouse or keyboard input doesn't work.

EDIT: Added my main mxml code. Is there way to create a "catch all" listener which would then feed events to the FP's Input class?

Comment: I think that the Flex components that are above the "flashpunk" are getting the events instead of it. Try to put "flashpunk" at very top and see if it gets the events. Another solution is to set the above  flex elements' mouseEnable property to false

Comment: I tried to add mouseEnable="false" but nothing really changed. I'm not sure how I could put flashpunk above the flex components either. Wouldn't that hijack events from flex components then? Is there a way to set some kind of catch all event listener to top level of application which then feeds events to FP's Input class? I added my application's main mxml to my first post.